# Legend filled.contour plot

Tags: r

I am trying to create a contour plot with filled.contour and I would like to change the size of the legend title and labels as well as the size of the legend itself. I have already the code for my data which is very similar to the volcano example (easier to replicate).

```
data(volcano)
filled.contour(volcano, color = terrain.colors, asp = 1)# simple

x <- 10*1:nrow(volcano)
y <- 10*1:ncol(volcano)
filled.contour(x, y, volcano, color = terrain.colors,
               plot.title = title(main = "The Topography of Maunga Whau",
                                  xlab = "Meters North", ylab = "Meters West"),
               plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(100, 800, by = 100))
                 axis(2, seq(100, 600, by = 100)) },
               key.title = title(main="Height\n(meters)"),
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(90, 190, by = 10),asp=1))# maybe also asp=1
```

I have tried to add cex and pch parameters but it seems not work.

```
key.title = title(main="Height\n(meters)",cex=0.5,pch = 1)
```

Suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `par(cex.main)` inside `plot.title` and `key.title`:

```
filled.contour(x, y, volcano, color = terrain.colors,
               plot.title = {par(cex.main=1);title(main = "The Topography of Maunga Whau",
                                  xlab = "Meters North", ylab = "Meters West")},
               plot.axes = { axis(1, seq(100, 800, by = 100))
                 axis(2, seq(100, 600, by = 100)) },
               key.title = {par(cex.main=0.3);title(main="Height\n(meters)")},
               key.axes = axis(4, seq(90, 190, by = 10),asp=1))# maybe also asp=1
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Martin, it is exactly what I needed. I must learn more about par() possibilities when plotting.